# C# SortedObservableCollection by string property of object

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting

Maybe this has already been answered, but I couldn't find in on Google. If it has been I apologize. I have a `SortedObservableCollection<TargetViewModel>` that I am trying to get in alphabetical order from A-Z based on a string property on `TargetViewModel`. I implemented `CompareTo` on `TargetViewModel`, the problem is that there's a special constant tab who's string property is just a + sign that we're using as a way to add a new tab. This needs to be to the right of all tabs and adding any new tab needs to fit in before the + sign and after a constant tab that should always be at the left most position. Is there a way to specify to tabs, on that is on the left and one on the right and order all tabs in between the two? i.e. | MainTab | Tab A | Tab B | Tab C | + |

Here's what my `CompareTo` function looks like:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return 1;
    TargetViewModel tvm = obj as TargetViewModel;
    if (tvm != null)
    {
        return string.Compare(tvm.Header, Header, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a TargetViewModel");
}
```

Comment: From your post it seems like there is no logic-based reason to have the `TargetViewModel`s sorted; it seems that the sorting is purely for the view. If that is the case, perhaps you should look at using a `CollectionViewSource` on the view (along with a custom sorter) instead of having a `SortedObservableCollection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following shows how to build a comparer that does what you want based on strings. It should be easy to apply to your situation:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> items = new List<string> {"+", "A", "B", "V", "MainTab"};
        items.Sort(new CustomComparer());
        items.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }

    class CustomComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return 0;
            if (x == null) return -1;
            if (y == null) return 1;
            if (x.Equals(y, StringComparison.Ordinal)) return 0;

            if (x.Equals("MainTab", StringComparison.Ordinal)) return -1;
            if (y.Equals("MainTab", StringComparison.Ordinal)) return 1;

            if (x.Equals("+", StringComparison.Ordinal)) return 1;
            if (y.Equals("+", StringComparison.Ordinal)) return -1;

            return string.CompareOrdinal(x, y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I just had to swap the returns!